# maps 3.2.0 package (r): how to put in the same plot multiple regions of a dataset?

Tags: r, maps, package, r-sf

I need the map of the [lombardy region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lombardy), in Italy.

When I run `map("italy")` however I can see that the dataset is divided at the province level, not the regional one. Lombardy is composed by 12 provinces. 
I can get the map of Milan (city and province) by doing `map("italy","Milan")` but it gives me an error when I do `map("italy","Lombardy")`.

My question is: how can I put in one map multiple provinces (those in the region of Lombardy)? Is it possible to delete the internal borders?

Comment: `map("italy", regions = c("Milan", "prov2",... "prov12"))` will draw multiple provinces

Answer (score 2):

From the `maps` help:

> This italy database comes from the NUTS III (Tertiary Administrative Units of the European Community) database of the United Nations Environment Programme (UNEP) GRID-Geneva data sets. **These were prepared around 1989, and so may be somewhat out of date.**

Back then Lombardy had only 10 provinces, so we'll use those.

```
library(maps)

lombardy_provs <- map('italy', c('Milan', 'Bergamo', 'Brescia', 'Como', 
                                 'Cremona', 'Lecco', 'Mantova', 'Varese', 
                                 'Pavia', 'Sondrio'), 
                      resolution = 0)
```

The `resolution = 0` argument is used to get the maximum resolution available, otherwise we'll get artifacts down the line.

[image]

We use the new `sf` (`simple features`) package to union these regions.

First we cast the `map` object to a `sf`

```
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.0, GDAL 2.1.1, proj.4 4.9.3

lombardy_sf_provs <- st_as_sf(lombardy_provs)
plot(lombardy_sf_provs)
```

[image]

Then we can 'union' them using `st_union()`

```
lombardy_sf <- st_union(lombardy_sf_provs)
plot(lombardy_sf, col = 'lightblue')
```

[image]

Imo the `sf` format is more suitable for any use than the `maps` format, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks @GGamba, that looks great! However when I try to install sf I get this error: `configure: error: sf is not compatible with GDAL versions below 2.0.0`. How can I upgrade this software GDAL? I have version 1.10.1 and I am on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `GDAL` is at that version for stable *unix. I'm actually upgrading it right now on a new Linux machine, using the code [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823023/gdal-install-failing-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts). I'll see how it goes

Comment: I ended up the hints from [this page](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/593ee48b34001fe3b383ea73ea57063ecf690732/.travis.yml) @gboffi You are right, Lecco wasn't there yet :)

Comment: I am sorry @GGamba , I am a little confused. All of those instructions are to be put in the terminal? Or are there some steps to be done in R?